# Verify User Has Added SSH Key To Git Profil Before Commiting/Pushing Projects In Bash

Tags: bash, git, gitlab

I'm wanting to write a bash script that verifies a user has created their SSH key on a gitlab server before the user clones or pushes any projects. Is there a `git` command that returns a true/false (0 or 1) that says "This person has their keys"?

I've tried a simple `ssh gitlab.server.url` and that seems to work, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution as I'm not wanting to verify they can ssh to the server, but rather their gitlab account has their SSH key(s) created to have the ability to clone/push projects. I was wondering if there was a specific `git` command.

Comment: I really wouldn't bother. *Any* `git` command will inform you if the necessary key is missing, by failing to connect. Git itself doesn't care about them; it's the underlying call to `ssh` that needs them. And it's also not the local Git that can tell; it's the remote server that will refuse the connection if the correct key is not presented.

Comment: Ok, I figured this would be the answer. I was creating a script to assist users in transferring their git projects from 1 git server (very old version of gitlab) to another git server (new version of gitlab). So the bash script clones their project from the old server onto their local directory, then attempt to push to the new server. However, if they don't have their SSH key on the new gitlab server, this step will fail. I was trying to have a validation check before I ever clone the project to their local directory. PS I clean up their directory so I don't leave the project on their local.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a cURL request to [GitLab Users API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#list-ssh-keys) and get the info on SSH keys for any user, given that you know their userId

```
curl --header "Private-Token: <your_PAT_here>" -X GET <your_GitLab_URL>/api/v4/users/<userId>/keys
```

In theory it works also with username, instead of userId, but I couldn't make it work. In order to get userId, I made an additional API call

```
curl --header "Private-Token: <your_PAT_here>" -X GET <your_GitLab_URL>/api/v4/users?username=<username_here>
```